# How to remove object from array within ng-repeat with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having an array with objects like [{...}, {...}] which I am outputting with ng-repeat. Then I have a delete button with a function to delete it.

Is there a simple way to delete it in AngularJS, perhaps with $index? Or I need to specify an ID on every object as an property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't apply a filter to reorder or filter your array, you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="delete($index)">{{item}}</div>
```

And the delete function:

```
$scope.items = [...];

$scope.delete = function (index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Another way to do it without filter problems: (ONLY IE9+)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'id'" ng-click="delete(item)">{{item}}</div>
```

And the delete function:

```
$scope.items = [...];

$scope.delete = function (item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/2/

Comment: and what happens if I have an "orderBy" directive next to the ng-repeat? the method will not work anymore?

Comment: @Johan the problem with the first option is that if you reorder the array in the view with a filter, the $index will be different that the index in the original array, so it will delete a different item.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example, using Jade too:

template.jade:

```
 label All Items
 ul.list-group
   li.list-group-item(ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: '_id'")
    strong {{item.name}}
 a.trash(ng-click='deleteItem(item)')
//a.trash is a bootstrap trash icon, but you don't need to use it.
```

controller.js:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item),1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

removeWith
comparison for each element in a collection to the given properties object,
returning an array without all elements that have equivalent property values.

```
  $scope.collection = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 1, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 2, name: 'baz' }
  ]

<tr ng-repeat="obj in collection | removeWith:{ id: 1 }">
  {{ obj.name }}
</tr>
```

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in collection | removeWith:{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }">
  {{ obj.name }}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to do it this way, but the listing was not actualized at runtime.

```
$scope.delete = function (index) {
    delete $scope.items[index];
}
```

Then with the answer given above by *Facundo Pedrazzini* did work properly for me.

```
$scope.delete = function (index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Version: `AngularJS v1.6.4`

Answer (score 0):

In blade.php

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr ng-repeat="name in planFormData.names track by $index">
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Plan Name<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="planFormData.names[$index].plan_name" name="plan_name" id="status-name" placeholder="Plan Name" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="JavaScript:Void(0);"><i class="icon-plus" ng-click="addRow($index)" ng-show="$last"></i></a>
           <a href="JavaScript:Void(0);"><i class="icon-trash" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" ng-show="$index != 0"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In controller.js

```
$scope.deleteRow = function($event, name) {
    var index = $scope.planFormData.names.indexOf(name);
    $scope.planFormData.names.splice(index, 1);    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6, I did similar for Multi Dimensional Array. It's working

```
  RemoveThisTimeSlot(i: number, j: number) {    
    this.service.formData.ConsultationModelInfo.ConsultationWeekList[i].TimeBlockList.splice(j, 1);
  }
```