# ng-model bind to element in ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How bind ng-model to element inside ng-repeat?
In fact i want to bind object in array to element and when type in input element create new input element with new ng-model. while in this example all ng-model are same.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.items = [];
    $scope.item = {
        phone:""
    };
    $scope.items.push($scope.item);

    $scope.addItem = function(index){
        if($scope.items[index+1] == null)
          $scope.items.push($scope.item);
        console.log($scope.items);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="line in items track by $index">
      <!-- typing here should auto update it's preview above -->
      <input ng-model="line.phone" ng-keydown="addItem($index)"/>
      <!-- many other fields here that will also affect the preview -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it what you want: `$scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.item));`?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: @ Ayush i want to create form dynamically.when type in input element add another input element.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this one. Note that I use

```
$scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.item))
```

to make a *copy* of object. Without this you always put reference to *same* object in array, so changing one of them causes others to be changed as well.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.items = [];
    $scope.item = {
        phone:""
    };
    $scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.item));

    $scope.addItem = function(index){
        if($scope.items[index+1] == null)
          $scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.item));
        console.log($scope.items);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="line in items track by $index">
      <!-- typing here should auto update it's preview above -->
      <input ng-model="line.phone" ng-keydown="addItem($index)"/>
      <!-- many other fields here that will also affect the preview -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how remove value when added new element?

Comment: @hadi, I think this was descried in another [_tread_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click) - it has perfect explanation. Just add `ng-click="remove(line)"` and add `remove` behaviour in your controller

Comment: when type in second input element it added new input element with first input element value. while i don't want this.

Comment: change also first occurrence of `$scope.items.push($scope.item);` with `$scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.item));`. See updated answer for details

Comment: thanks. its work correctly but in console appear this error: Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ngModel/nonassign?

Comment: there is no error for me, are you sure it comes from exactly this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass like `$scope.items.push($scope.item);` then `$scope.item` is reference to the same object and it will push to the array multiple times, because objects are referenced types, if you push `primitive` data types it will act differently,

define the `item` local in the function,

```
$scope.addItem = function(index){
        if($scope.items[index+1] == null) {
            var item = {
                 phone:""
            };
        }
        $scope.items.push(item );
        console.log($scope.items);
  }
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.items = [];
    var item = {
                 phone:""
    };
    $scope.items.push(item);

     $scope.addItem = function(index){
        if($scope.items[index+1] == null) {
            var item = {
                 phone:""
            };
            $scope.items.push(item );
            console.log($scope.items);
        }            
      }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="line in items track by $index">
      <!-- typing here should auto update it's preview above -->
      <input ng-model="line.phone" ng-keydown="addItem($index)"/>
      <!-- many other fields here that will also affect the preview -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. its work correctly but in console appear this error: Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ngModel/nonassign?

Comment: umm dont know what the exact error, in this demo there is no console errors :(

Comment: @ K.Toress. ok. that is right and no error in console. thanks very much. your answer and simoco answer is correct and i don't know which accept :(

Comment: :D ha haa go with the one make sense to you :) no worries

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the key as array key of the model

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, line) in items track by $index">
  <input ng-model="line.phone[key]" ng-keydown="addItem($index)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you forget to mention what it actually does: `<div>{{items|json}}</div>` - I don't think this is what OP wants

Comment: OP should declare phone as an array. Like `$scope.item = {
        phone: []
    };` then your above code will work perfectly :-)