# How to Add and Edit and Delete table data using Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to **Add** and **Edit**  and **Delete** table list data.

With my knowledge I was able to write the below code for adding a new user and I don't know how to perform the edit and delete operation.

I searched lot in google but did not get proper solution.

Can some one help me please?

### index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

    <div class="w3-container">

    <h3>Users</h3>

    <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{ user.fName }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.lName }}</td>
         <td>
          <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="editUser()">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="deleteUser()">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br></br>

    <h3>Create New User</h3>

    <form>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" ng-model="fName" placeholder="First Name">
      <br>
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" ng-model="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
        <br></br>

    <button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-ripple" ng-click="addUser()">Save Changes</button>

    </form>

    </div>

    <script src= "myUsers.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

### myUsers:-

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.users = [
    {id:1, fName:'Hege', lName:"Pege" },
    {id:2, fName:'Kim',  lName:"Pim" },
    {id:3, fName:'Sal',  lName:"Smith" },
    {id:4, fName:'Jack', lName:"Jones" },
    {id:5, fName:'John', lName:"Doe" },
    {id:6, fName:'Peter',lName:"Pan" }
    ];

    $scope.addUser=function(){
        $scope.users.push({
            'fName':users.fName,
            'lName':users.lName,
        });
       }

    $scope.editUser=function(){

      }

    $scope.deleteUser=function(){

      }

});
```

Comment: I don't know where you searched. Possible duplicate of [Add, Remove & Update specific data In JSON in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839697/add-remove-update-specific-data-in-json-in-angularjs)

Comment: Please check this https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/PQOOOM

Answer (score 1):

Please check the tutorial from [here](http://www.javasavvy.com/angularjs-table-form-edit-tutorial/).

For your reference use following code and check the codepen to [here](https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/PQOOOM).

In template

```
     <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
       <span ng-if="!user.editFlag">{{ user.fName }}</span>
       <input ng-if="user.editFlag" ng-model="user.fName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <span ng-if="!user.editFlag">{{ user.fName }}</span>
      <input ng-if="user.editFlag" ng-model="user.lName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="editUser($index)"><span ng-if="!user.editFlag">Edit<span><span ng-if="!user.editFlag">Save</span></button>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="deleteUser($index)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

In your controller

```
    // edit data
    $scope.editUser = function (index) {

        if($scope.users.length){
          // its checking with your edit flag to save or edit
          $scope.users[index].editFlag = !$scope.users[index].editFlag;

        }

    };
    // Delete data
    $scope.deleteUser = function (index) {

        // Remove from main records (using index)
        if($scope.users.length){
          $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

Please check this sample to [here](https://gist.github.com/MrSaints/8874103).

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: Not for me. It needs OP. OP need a flag variable to show and hide the editable fields inside the table.

Comment: you will use flag in your user object iteslf

Comment: Exactly this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839697/add-remove-update-specific-data-in-json-in-angularjs

Comment: yeah maybe u will check this http://www.javasavvy.com/angularjs-table-form-edit-tutorial/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165262/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score -1):

These changes will make addUser functionality work

```
   $scope.addUser=function(index){
      if(index){
      $scope.users[index].fName=$scope.fName;
      $scope.users[index].lName=$scope.lName;
    }
    else{
    $scope.users.push({
        'fName':$scope.fName,
        'lName':$scope.lName,
    });
   }
   $scope.editMode=false;
    $scope.fName='';
    $scope.lName='';     
}

    $scope.editUser=function(index){
    $scope.editMode=true;
    $scope.editIndex=index;
    $scope.fName=$scope.users[index].fName;
    $scope.lName=$scope.users[index].lName;
}

$scope.deleteUser=function(index){
   $scope.users.splice(index,1)
}
```

Here is working version of above problem 
with changes in  html and js code

https://embed.plnkr.co/ecKSDwW2hfU9t7cj4rZP/

Comment: Html file do have some changes .You can go through plunker link

Comment: Bu duplicate records should not allow @shilpidev

Comment: i didnt get on how you are putting duplicate records check ? i mean is it 'id' or 'fName'?

Comment: using id i would like to check

Comment: step 1:  https://prnt.sc/ifg0h5  step2: https://prnt.sc/ifg085  step 3: https://prnt.sc/ifg0yd edit seems to work fine. Dont get where its stuck

Comment: added id attribute also while adding new user: $scope.users.push({
        'id':newId,
        'fName':$scope.fName,
        'lName':$scope.lName,
    }); Hope this may help  https://plnkr.co/edit/ecKSDwW2hfU9t7cj4rZP?p=preview