# How to add Data to Specific index of json array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I was created table data and edit button and i am getting problem when i was trying to add edit data to specific row.

Here my plunkr :- http://plnkr.co/edit/QKz7nu458i8Il4OLmAyw?p=preview

Here HTML page

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type='checkbox' ng-modal='isall' ng-click='selectallrows()'></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>EDIT</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat='p in person' ng-class="{'success':tableselection[$index]}">
                        <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='tableselection[$index]'></td>
                        <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.name}}</td>
                        <td><button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='edit(p.id)'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
<div ng-show='editabledata'>
      <form role='form' class='form-horizontal'>

        <div class='form-group'>
      <label>Id :-</label>
      <input type='text' ng-model='pid' class='from-group col-sm-2'></div>
      <div class='form-group'>
      <label>Name:-</label>
      <input type='text' ng-model='pname' class='from-group col-sm-2'>
      </div>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='saveeditdata(pid)'>Save</button>
      <button clas='btn btn-primary' ng-click='canceleditdata()'>Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here my .js

```
$scope.person=[
        {id:1,name:'devendher'},
        {id:2,name:'Macha'},
        {id:3,name:'Macha devendher'}
        ];

    $scope.editabledata=false;
  $scope.edit=function(id){
    $scope.editabledata=true;

   for(i=0;i<$scope.person.length;i++){

     if($scope.person[i].id==id)
   {
     $scope.pid=$scope.person[i].id;
     $scope.pname=$scope.person[i].name;
   }

   }
  }


  $scope.saveeditdata=function(id){
    for(i=0;i<$scope.person.length;i++){
      if($scope.person[i].id==id){
        $scope.person[i].push({'id':$scope.pid,'name':$scope.pname})
      }
    }


  }
```

i got error " $scope.person[i].push " is not a function
Is there any alternate way to add data to specific index of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
$scope.person.push({...})
```

Or

```
$scope.person[i] = {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very over complicated and you aren't taking advantage of using a single object for the form data. In addition you are using different property names for the editing vs original object. All the loops you are doing are unnecessary

**Much simpler steps:**

To edit object, pass whole object to controller function :

```
  <button  ng-click='edit(p)'>
```

In controller make copy of object and store reference to the selected one to update later

```
$scope.edit=function(person){ 
   $scope.editabledata = true;
   $scope.selectedItem = person;
   $scope.editItem = angular.copy(person);
}
```

In edit form use full object reference in `ng-model`. No need to create individual variables, use the properties that already exist

```
ID :  <input ng-model="editItem.id">
Name: <input ng-model="editItem.name">
```

In the save function extend the original object with the updated one

```
$scope.saveeditdata=function(){
   // merge updates
   angular.extend($scope.selectedItem , $scope.editItem);
   // reset
   $scope.editabledata = false;
   $scope.editItem = {};

}
```

For delete see : [How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click/15454424#15454424)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTUuMePbg8Bl8VCecMNG?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah,Thank you very much :)