# deleting an angular object from an array - $$hashKey?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a dialogue that adds a Master Carton to an array of Master Cartons.

A repeater shows 1 or more Master Cartons:

```
        <div ng-repeat="carton in dimensionsModalVm.masterCartons">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Length</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="length" min="0" max="999" class="form-control input-inline input-xs" type="number" placeholder="Enter Length" ng-model="carton.dimensions.length" required /> inches
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Weight</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="weight" min="0" max="999" class="form-control input-inline input-xs" type="number" placeholder="Enter Weight" ng-model="carton.dimensions.weight" required /> pounds
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click=" dimensionsModalVm.addMasterCarton()" type="button">Add another master carton</button>
```

My creation of the first MC on page init is called

```
function dimensionsModalInstanceController($http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, toastr, cart, masterCarton, CartObservable) {

    vm.addMasterCarton = function () {
        vm.masterCartons.push({
            length: 0,
            weight: 0
        });
    };
    vm.addMasterCarton();
```

((
For what it's worth, dimensionsModalInstanceController is created within the previous modal's controller here - so dimensionsModalInstanceController is dimensionsModalVm:

```
function masterCartonModalInstanceController($uibModal, $uibModalInstance, cart) {
    vm.yes = function(size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'dimensionsModalContent',
            controller: 'dimensionsModalInstanceController',
            controllerAs: 'dimensionsModalVm',
            ...
```

))

To add another MC, the button simply calls vm.addMasterCarton.

...

Now I want to be able to delete a MC. I've added a [X] in the corner of each MC.

```
        <div ng-repeat="carton in dimensionsModalVm.masterCartons">
                <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button" ng-click="dimensionsModalVm.deleteMasterCarton(this)">X</button>

    vm.deleteMasterCarton = function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.carton);
        console.log(vm.masterCartons);
    };
```

My output is:

```
Object {length: 1, weight: 1, $$hashKey: "object:51"}
```

and

```
Object array
[
    {
    $$hashKey: "object:33",
        length: 1,
        weight: 1
    },{

    $$hashKey: "object:51",
        length: 1,
        weight: 1
    }
]
```

How do I tell it to delete the object from the array? I see matching $$hashKeys, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

I don't want to have to invent a unique ID to track them.

If I used **track by index** on my MC repeater, would they get out-of-place as I delete them?

This article:
[How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click)

suggests this *should* work:

```
         var index = vm.masterCartons.indexOf(obj);
         vm.masterCartons.splice(index, 1);
```

Unfortunately, it does not delete the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. 
Using track by ... ($index, id, etc) is always good idea. You do not need to worry about track by and possible issues for your list.
Second.

Change

```
dimensionsModalVm.deleteMasterCarton(this)
```

to

```
dimensionsModalVm.deleteMasterCarton(carton)
```

and try again with "index of"

Comment: Ah! carton is what it wants! Thank you.

Comment: Also found another, simpler solution that doesn't even need the controller - does it right in the DOM:
 <button ng-click="dimensionsModalVm.masterCartons.splice($index, 1)">X</button>

Comment: @DaveC426913 That splice solution is pretty sweet. Thanks for the tip.