# How to delete item from array angularjs?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, oop

Why I can't remove item from array posts?

html tag for delete item

```
html tag
<span ng-click="remove($index)"> delete</span>

//AngularJS method where I try to delete item
blog.remove = function(index) {
blog.posts.splice(index, 1);
};

//Angular array posts
blog.posts = [{
    "title": "Blog Post One",
    "comments": [
      {
        "body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. ",
        "author": "trollguy87"
      }
    ]}];
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: one possibility is that index you are passing in your remove function is wrong. Try to see index by console.log, before that splice statement.

Comment: Maybe post a bit more code. Hard to tell exactly what's wrong by just looking at these fragment.

On problem I see is `remove` is getting called on scope. But you're definition is on the blog itself. So, shouldn't it be `blog.remove($index)`?

And, what is the `$index`? Coming from some sort of `repeat` I assume

Comment: Please post code containing the `ng-repeat` part, it is currently hard to figure how you manage `$scope/vm`

Comment: This code can be correct if only you have `var blog = $scope;` because you call `$scope.remove` by `ng-click="remove()"`

Comment: please share more code from html part of your program

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the item to the function and getting the index from the item.

As mentioned in the below thread.

[How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ng-repeat` then this can help:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in posts"> <!-- This will use your blog.posts -->
    <button ng-click="posts.splice($index, 1)"> 

        {{key.title}}
    </button>
</div>
```