# How to delete element from object?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-click` event:

```
removeFile(file, $index);
```

Where `file` is object:

```
File
$$hashKey:"object:572"
lastModified:1487594253749
lastModifiedDate:Mon Feb 20 2017 15:37:33 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
name:"1 — копия — копия — копия.jpg"
size:315074
type:"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath:""
```

I try to remove object mentioned above from array `Files`:

I tried:

```
delete $scope.files[index];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click)

Comment: Judging by the accepted answer, it seems like you are asking how to remove an element from an array, rather than an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splice :

```
$scope.removeFile = function(file){
    var index = $scope.files.indexOf(file);
    $scope.files.splice(index,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of delete use splice

```
var index = $scope.files.indexOf(index);
  if(index>=0)
    $scope.files.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this using filter function of array

```
$scope.removeFile = function(file){
    $scope.files = $scope.files.filter(function(fileItem) {
        return fileItem.name != file.name;
    });
}
```