# Angularjs create table with add/delete row, from ng-repeat in object of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have list of objects that go with ng-repeat to create a table:

```
  $scope.fieldData.gridDetails =
   {"1": {
    "Name" : "Test A",
    "Country" : "Germany",
    "City" : "Berlin"
  }, "2": {
    "Name" : "Test B",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "Chicago"
  }, "3": {
    "Name" : "Test C",
    "Country" : "France",
    "City" : "Paris"
  }, "4": {
    "Name" : "Test D",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "New York"
  }
  }
});
```

I want to make a code to remove object, like if I deleted "3": { "Name": "Test C" ...
I want it should be:

```
  $scope.fieldData.gridDetails =
  {"1": {
    "Name" : "Test A",
    "Country" : "Germany",
    "City" : "Berlin"
  }, "2": {
    "Name" : "Test B",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "Chicago"
  }, "3": {
    "Name" : "Test D",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "New York"
  }
  }
});
```

I made this code but its not working:

```
  $scope.removeItem = function(index){ 
    $scope.fieldData.gridDetails[index] = undefined;
  }
```

but my code keep it :

```
  $scope.fieldData.gridDetails =
  {"1": {
    "Name" : "Test A",
    "Country" : "Germany",
    "City" : "Berlin"
  }, "2": {
    "Name" : "Test B",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "Chicago"
  }, "4": {
    "Name" : "Test D",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "City" : "New York"
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: try to splice the array at that index

Comment: Check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454424/2079271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete an item or object from an array using ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click)

Comment: I tried it, and it show an error message in the console:
 TypeError: $scope.fieldData.gridDetails.splice is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.removeItem = function(index){ 
    $scope.fieldData.gridDetails.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Try that.

Comment: I tried it, and it show an error message:

TypeError: $scope.fieldData.gridDetails.splice is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your $scope.fieldData.gridDetails object as an array like below.

```
$scope.fieldData.gridDetails =
  [
  {
    "1": {
      "Name": "Test A",
      "Country": "Germany",
      "City": "Berlin"
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "Name": "Test B",
      "Country": "USA",
      "City": "Chicago"
    }
  },
  {
    "3": {
      "Name": "Test C",
      "Country": "France",
      "City": "Paris"
    }
  },
  {
    "4": {
      "Name": "Test D",
      "Country": "USA",
      "City": "New York"
    }
  }
];
```

then create a function for removing the objects

```
$scope.removeItem = function(index){
    $scope.fieldData.gridDetails.splice(index,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the awkward structure to an array:

```
var x = $scope.fieldData.gridDetails;
var y = Object.keys(x).map(k => x[k]);
```

Use the form to `slice` and `push` the array;

To convert the array back to the awkward structure:

```
var z = y.reduce((a,x,i) => (a[i+1]=x), {});
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)