# Compute the newly pushed data in array using loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, loops, lodash

I am having trouble in proper calculation of numerical values in an array inside a loop.

**Scenario**

- The `tbody` generates a list of dynamic values.
- The `button` inside `td` has a `function` called `preBookThis()` with `params`.
- When the User clicks the `button`, it will trigger the `function` then `push` the `data` into an `array variable`.
- Upon *pushing*, there will be a `for loop` that will iterate and compute the values. *(`$scope.nights` is the two dates - ie. 2018-05-05 and 2018-05-07, so it will have a value of **2)***

**The problem**

- Lets imagine that there were *three rows* in the `tbody` and have the following values.

  `$scope.nights = 2;
   row1 = 100;
   row2 = 200;
   row3 = 300;`
- When the user clicks the `button` in *row 1* the computation works and performs as expected

  `amount_row1 = 200;`

but...

- When the user clicks the `button` in *row 2*, the computed values of the first row will be doubled.

  `amount_row1 = 400;
  amount_row2 = 400;`

and also...

- When the user clicks the `button` in *row 3*, the computed values of the first row and second row will be doubled again.

  `amount_row1 = 800;
  amount_row2 = 800;
  amount_row3 = 600;`

**The final output should be:**

```
 amount_row1 = 200;
 amount_row2 = 400;
 amount_row3 = 600;
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="room in roomsDisplay">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="col-md-6"><img ng-src="images/rooms/{{room.room_image}}"></div>         
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top: 20px;"><input type="button" 
                ng-click="preBookthis({room})" class="btn btn-primary" 
                value="Book this Room"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.preBookthis = function(data){
    $scope.totalAmount = 0;
    $scope.bookData.push({ 
        'room_name': data.room.room_name, 
        'price': data.room.price,
        'amount': $scope.amount,
        'id' : data.room.rooms_type_id
    });

    _.forEach($scope.bookData, function(value, key){
        value.amount = value.amount * $scope.nights;
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't help, since I don't know enough about the subject. But I'd like to commend you on a very detailed and high quality answer. I'm sure that'll increase the chances of getting answered.

Comment: I really appreciate your commendation. I hope someone can answer because I am really frustrated in this, can't solve it.

Comment: What is the last line in the method for?

Comment: Also, you seem to be multiplying by `$scope.nights` twice.

Comment: I updated my codes in the last part, removed the unnecessary codes that may confuse others. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the calculations only once when you add the new object and don't loop over all the others that have had it calculated already

Something like:

```
$scope.preBookthis = function(data){
    $scope.totalAmount = 0;
    $scope.bookData.push({ 
        'room_name': data.room.room_name, 
        'price': data.room.price,
        'amount': $scope.amount * $scope.nights,// calculate only for this item
        'id' : data.room.rooms_type_id
    });  
}
```

Comment: nice. Didn't think about that. Certainly better than my idea :D

Comment: I didn't see that one. Really good job. Now, my only problem is the `total_amount` of the all `pushed` data. Thank you.

Comment: Can use the loop to get total or just add new amount to existing total

Comment: Nice, got it working both. Anyway, I have other problems but it is not related to question I posted. It is the opposite of this one though, I will try to solve it myself first. Thank you.

Comment: Opposite meaning how to remove one? If so this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453979/how-do-i-delete-an-item-or-object-from-an-array-using-ng-click/15454424#15454424

Comment: Yeah. Anyway, I already got it working. I just modifed my exisiting code on that one and followed the tip you gave. Thanks,

Comment: The link you gave, I think it is also where I got the answer on how to remove the specific row in the table. Really appreciate your help. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

The problem rises from `$scope.bookData` being changed entirely whenever the function is called.

When the function is called, `$scope.bookData` might contain objects for other rows. those objects have an `amount` value. In your loop, you multiply that value by `$scope.nights` (which is 2).

So you are multiplying **all** the rows' values by 2.

You are repeatedly changing the values for `amount`.

try this:

```
_.forEach($scope.bookData, function(value, key){
    value.amount = (key+1) * $scope.nights*100;
});
```

EDIT:

Actually, the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191323/3625036) features a better solution.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. But I believe charlietfl answers is the better one. Thank you.